# Using Spring Security with a standalone Tomcat doing authentication

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, spring-boot

I want Tomcat (or rather the admin) to handle the user management.
In Spring I just want to secure some endpoints (index.html and two RESTful controllers) and bind it to either a user or, even better, a group/role.

I want to avoid using xml config inside Spring and use just classes and annotations.
Xml config in tomcat is ok :-)

Booting up spring I see a log entry

> 2014-06-04 11:37:31.676  INFO 27296 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration :
>
> Using default password for application endpoints: 543fbdb8-c5d0-4b1b-b7ce-cd6fd008520a
>
> 2014-06-04 11:37:31.775  INFO 27296 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5867ecdd, ...
>
> ...
>
> 2014-06-04 11:37:31.794  INFO 27296 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
>
> ...
>
> 2014-06-04 11:37:31.907  INFO 27296 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController]

Trying to call upon the secured route I get a login form, yet using the information from the *tomcat-users.xml* I get an error **Invalid username and password.**.

So what am I missing?

### Setup

I have

- vanilla Apache Tomcat 8.0.8
- a modified *conf/tomcat-users.xml*
- a modified *conf/server.xml*
- a cloned deployable version of the [Securing Spring Web Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web) in my local branch and in this folder (intellij module), see [github repo](https://github.com/rbecher/gs-securing-web/tree/standalone/standalone)

### Configuration

#### Spring

See the *WebSecurityConfig* class.

#### tomcat-users.xml

```
<!-- ... --->
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="ROLE_stakeholder"/>
<user username="stakeholder" password="Foobarbaz" roles="ROLE_stakeholder,manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
<!-- ... --->
```

#### server.xml

```
<!-- ... --->
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    <!-- ... --->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
</Engine>
```

Comment: You have to make tomcat do the authentication and use pre-authentication in Spring Security. IMHO you are making it to complex (splitting the process over 2 components). Why wouldn't it be possible to do all with Spring Security?

Comment: I don't want to deal with the user management myself and the admin later wants to use some other authentication backend (ldap probably).
On the other hand, the admin should not have to know, which endpoints to secure ...

Comment: Why would using Spring Security force you to do user management yourself? Also switching from properties files to ldap is a matter of configuration in Spring Security. If you simply externalize the security configuration you can modify whatever you want.

Comment: The only working examples I've seen do something like [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-securing-web/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/WebSecurityConfig.java#L27-L32). That's working for me, too. I just don't want to do it this way, but use Tomcat's AuthenticationManager (or whatever is the equivalent)

Comment: Instead of looking at samples using in-memory settings have you actually read the reference guide?!

Comment: I tried at least, yes. I'm just looking at the preauth-samples, thx for the pointer